# Parametric integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

For $0 \le \alpha \lt \infty$ and $p \gt 0$ evaluate integral $$I(\alpha, p) = \int_1^\infty e^{-\alpha x} \frac{\cos x}{x^p} \, dx$$ This should be solved by using theorem about differentiation by parameter. I've tried with both parameters $p$ and $\alpha$. In both cases 
I've managed to prove that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} f(x, \alpha, p)$ and $\frac \partial {\partial p} f(x, \alpha, p)$ are continuous by $(x, \alpha, p) \in [1, \infty) \times [0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$, where $f(x, \alpha, p) = e^{-\alpha x} \frac{\cos x}{x^p}$. Also, I've manged to prove convergence of $\int_1^\infty e^{-\alpha x} \frac{\cos x}{x^p} \, dx$ and uniform convergence by both $\alpha$ and $p$ of $\int_1^\infty \frac \partial {\partial \alpha} f(x, \alpha, p) \,dx$ and $\int_1^\infty \frac \partial {\partial p} f(x, \alpha, p) \, dx$ respectively (although I could not prove convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac \partial {\partial \alpha} \, ex$ for $p \in (0, 1)$). Now, I should evaluate one of those integrals, but it was too hard for me. Any help or advice is appreciated, and solution particularly.

Comment: With the lower limit as $1$, I doubt that there is a closed form solution here.

Comment: So is there anything I could do about it, or am I just stucked with this problem?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/pri/get/PMF/Druga%20godina/Analiza%204/Rokovi/Analiza_4___2__Kol__2016_.pdf?_subject_uid=218862874&w=AAATEs4Cr1uv1S6EZ8VQsc__j3RnHD1xf0tJFbZ_-0WOTw

Comment: The link doesn't work

Comment: https://www.yumpu.com/xx/document/view/58758116/analiza-4-2-kol-2016-

Comment: Oh, but could I instead of differentiation by alpha or p integrate by alpha or p? I mean, what if the subintegral function is an integral by p or alpha? Or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: I meant,  it's obvious I can use differentiating  under the integral, but I do not get anything useful... What if subintegral function is a Riemann-integral by alpha or p (inside the integral by x), so I could change order of integration. But... I am unable to notice it. Those are only two theorems we used for solving parametric integrals.